# Output multiple losses added by add_loss in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multipleoutputs

I've investigated the Keras example for [custom loss layer demonstrated by a Variational Autoencoder (VAE)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e8484633473c340defbe03a092be2d4856d56302/examples/variational_autoencoder.py). They have only one loss-layer in the example while the VAE's objective consists out of two different parts: Reconstruction and KL-Divergence.
However, I'd like to plot/visualize how these two parts evolve during training and split the single custom loss into two loss-layer:

**Keras Example Model:**

[image]

**My Model:**

[image]

Unfortunately, Keras just outputs one single loss value in the for my multi-loss example as can be seen in [my Jupyter Notebook example](https://gist.github.com/tik0/e43e6d5d65f822f0a09aa8fa181de1e7) where I've implemented both approaches.
Does someone know how to get the values per loss which were added by `add_loss`?
And additionally, how does Keras calculate the single loss value, given multiple `add_loss` calls (Mean/Sum/...?)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed not supported, and currently discussed on different places on the web. The solution can be obtained by adding your losses again as a separate metric after the compile step (also discussed [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9459#issuecomment-469282443))

This results in something like this (specifically for a VAE):

```
reconstruction_loss = mse(K.flatten(inputs), K.flatten(outputs))
kl_loss = beta*K.mean(- 0.5 * 1/latent_dim * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1))

model.add_loss(reconstruction_loss)
model.add_loss(kl_loss)
model.compile(optimizer='adam')

model.metrics_tensors.append(kl_loss)
model.metrics_names.append("kl_loss")

model.metrics_tensors.append(reconstruction_loss)
model.metrics_names.append("mse_loss")
```

For me this gives an output like this:

```
Epoch 1/1
252/252 [==============================] - 23s 92ms/step - loss: 0.4336 - kl_loss: 0.0823 - mse_loss: 0.3513 - val_loss: 0.2624 - val_kl_loss: 0.0436 - val_mse_loss: 0.2188
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm using the version 2.2.4-tf of Keras and the solution above didn't work for me.
Here is the solution I found (to continue the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025570/12066144) of **dumkar**):

```py
reconstruction_loss = mse(K.flatten(inputs), K.flatten(outputs))
kl_loss = beta*K.mean(- 0.5 * 1/latent_dim * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1))

model.add_loss(reconstruction_loss)
model.add_loss(kl_loss)

model.add_metric(kl_loss, name='kl_loss', aggregation='mean')
model.add_metric(reconstruction_loss, name='mse_loss', aggregation='mean')

model.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the extension! This is, in fact, the only feasible solution in tf-keras (aka tensorflow 2.0).

Comment: I've implemented, just as a reference, your proposed solution for the standard VAE Keras example here: https://gist.github.com/tik0/6aa42cabb9cf9e21567c3deb309107b7

Comment: @ValentinVIGNAL Thank you for the answer. can you please tell me (curious and want to learn) how you understood/thought of passing the aggregation ='mean' argument to the add_metric. I don't see any where any example that uses other than the function, name arguments. There are **kwargs but not sure what they are referring to.

Comment: Using a newer version of TF (2.2.0), you need to move the `model.compile` call after the `model.add_metric` calls, otherwise you get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DictWrapper'` error (I've proposed this as an edit to this post).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer is not straight forward and furthermore, Keras does not support this feature out of the box.
However, I've implemented a solution where each loss-layer outputs the loss and a customized callback function records it after every epoch. The solution for my multi-headed example can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/tik0/7c03ad11580ae0d69c326ac70b88f395